# How can I merge multiple shapfiles with shared polygons in QGIS (3.8.0) without ending up with double attributes?

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-3, attribute-table, merge

I have multiple shapefiles for different subspecies. The habitat range is devided into small hydrobasins (lvl 10) and I want to merge the ranges for subspecies to get a final species range. Naturally the subspecies have ranges that overlap, meaning certain lvl 10 basins are occupied by >1 subspecies (see image attached). If I simply merge this shapefiles, then I may get double attributes for these two polygons. The easiest thing to do would just be to delete the polygons from one of the two subspecies and then merge the files, but if there are thousands of cases it would be quite time consuming to do this (and I might miss some). Is there a simple way to delete this overlap for all instances before merging the files? I have tried using the Check Geometries plugin to find and remove duplicates, but aftering running the command, there were somehow no cases of overlap to be found.

I am quite new to QGIS.

[image: here the green and pink subspecies share two polygons completely]

Comment: You write "I have multiple shapefiles for different subspecies". Does this mean you have one shapefile per subspecies? In the merged shapefile you're trying to produce, do you want to preserve the LVL10 basins, or do you want a single polygon that represents the combined range of the species? What attributes (fields) do the shapefiles have? Do you want to preserve any of these attributes in the merged file?

Comment: Yes, I have one shapefile for each subspecies. I do want to preserve the LVL10 basins in the final range map and keep all of the attributes shared by both subspecies (my files all have the same attributes with the same names, etc)

Answer (score 1):

"Dissolve" is the tool you're looking for. You can also use the plugin "Dissolve with stats" if you want to calculate the sum of subspecies within a main basin for example.

EDIT: you have also the "Agregate" tool

Comment: I believe this would erase my lvl 10 subunits, no? Is it possible to use this method and keep all of my basins and their attributes?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're tring to do. Could you provide more details in your question (attribute tables for example) ?

There is also the "agregate" tool that may help you out !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an attribute (field) that identifies the LVL10 basin, I would join each subspecies shapefile to a new combined shapefile, using the LVL10 id as the join field. When defining the join you can decide which fields to carry into the join, presumably avoiding any fields that are duplicates in the two shapefiles. You can then use the field calculator to combine fields if desired. For example, if you have a population count for each subspecies, you can sum these to get the total population for the species. This will be a multi-step process, joining each subspecies in turn to the combined file.